# how to display multi select array data in select box in angularjs in rest api

Tags: php, angularjs, rest

My data is coming in this format

```
{"doctor_id":45,"d_name":"Dr. Shailesh Puntambekar","email":"xxxx@yahoo.com","phone":0,"speciality":"2,24,25","department":"1","qualification":""}
```

i need to fetch multiple speciality in select box

my code to fetch speciality is

```
<select class="form-control" multiple ng-multiple="true" ng-model="doctor.speciality" name="speciality">
               <option value="">Speciality</option>
               <option ng-repeat="speciality1 in speciality" value="{{speciality1.speciality_id}}" ng-selected="{{speciality1.speciality_id}} == {{doctor.speciality}}">{{speciality1.speciality}}</option>

</select>
```

my controller to fetch data is like this

```
myapp.controller('updatedoctor', ['$scope', '$http','services','$location','doctor','speciality','department',
function($scope,$http,services,$location,doctor,speciality,department) {

     $scope.editorOptions = {
    language: 'en',
    uiColor: '#553C64'
};

    services.getSpeciality().then(function(data){
    $scope.speciality = data.data;
})

services.getDepartment().then(function(data){
    $scope.department = data.data;
})


var original = doctor.data;
var original1 = speciality.data;
var original2 = department.data;

$scope.doctor = angular.copy(original);
$scope.isClean = function() {
    return angular.equals(original, $scope.doctor);
}

$scope.speciality = angular.copy(original1);
$scope.isClean = function() {
    return angular.equals(original1, $scope.speciality);
}

$scope.department = angular.copy(original2);
$scope.isClean = function() {
    return angular.equals(original2, $scope.department);
}
$scope.updateDoctor = function(doctor,updatedoctor_info_form) {
    if(updatedoctor_info_form.$invalid) {
        $scope.invalidSubmitAttempt = true;
        return;
    }else{

      var file = $('#cover').val();

       if(file != '') {


                                 $("#updatedoctor_info_form").ajaxSubmit({
                                                url: custom_url+'video.php',
                                                type:'post',                                                   
                                                enctype:'multipart/form-data',
                                                success: function(data, status, headers, config){
                                                    if(data=='0'){

                                                        }else{


                                                            var speciality = $scope.doctor.speciality;
                                                          $scope.doctor.speciality=speciality.toString();

                                                            $scope.doctor.profile_image=data;
                                                            services.updateDoctor(doctor);
                                                        $.simplyToast('Record Updated Successfully!', 'success');
                                                    //    $state.go('dashboard.doctor.manage');
                                                        }



                                                },
                                                error:function(){alert('error');}
                                        });

        }else{

    services.updateDoctor(doctor);
  }


}
 }
}]);
```

my service.js to fetch doctor data and speciality data is like this

```
obj.getDoctor = function(DoctorID){
    return $http.get(serviceBase + 'doctors/' + DoctorID);
}

obj.getSpeciality = function(){
    return $http.get(serviceBase + 'specialities');
}
```

my App.js is like this

```
.state('dashboard.doctor.updatedoctor', {
          url: '/update/:id',
          templateUrl:'views/doctors/update.html',
          controller:'updatedoctor',
          resolve: {
                doctor: function(services,$stateParams){
                  var DoctorID = $stateParams.id;
                  return services.getDoctor(DoctorID);
                },
                speciality: function(services){

                  return services.getSpeciality();
                },
             department: function(services){

                  return services.getDepartment();
                }
              }
     })
```

Comment: Please also add the angularjs code so that we can see what you've already tried to do.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this [Code](https://jsfiddle.net/0cuvuzd8/2/)

> //html

```
<select  ng-model="obj.category1" ng-options="item1 for  item1 in abms" >
     <option  value="" ></option>
</select>
```

> // js

```
.filter('findobj', function () {
 return function (dataobj, multipleVlaue) {
     if (!multipleVlaue) return dataobj;
     return dataobj.filter(function (news) {
         var tofilter = [];

         angular.forEach(multipleVlaue,function(v,i){ 
          tofilter.push(v);
         });

         return news.CategoryList.some(function (category) {
        return tofilter.indexOf(category.DisplayName)>-1;
     });

     });
 };
 })
```